# How to pass event.target values?

Tags: reactjs

Here is my code. Whenever I trigger onFocus on one input box another input box also changes its input type. I just want that particular box should change type at the time of focus.

```html
this.state = {type: 'text'};
   onFocus() {this.setState({ type: 'time'});}
   onBlur() {this.setState({type: 'text'});}

<Form.Control type={this.state.type} onFocus={()=>this.onFocus()} onBlur={()=>this.onBlur()} placeholder="Shop opens" />

<Form.Control placeholder="Shop closes" type={this.state.type} onFocus={()=>this.onFocus()} onBlur={()=>this.onBlur()} />
```

Comment: If you want them to do different things you should give them different onFocus functions and state vars.

Comment: Since you use `type={this.state.type}` for both boxes, of cause both changes when the state changes. Create a different state attribute like `this.state.shopOpensType` and `this.state.shopClosesType`

Comment: so pass the event to the method??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are only using one state property for both inputs.

Rather than storing the `type`, you could store the current focused input.

Untested code, but you could do something like:

```
this.state = {focused: null};
   onFocus(inputName) {this.setState({ focused: inputName });}
   onBlur() {this.setState({ focused: null });}

<Form.Control type={this.state.focused === 'opens' ? 'time' : 'text'} onFocus={()=>this.onFocus('opens')} onBlur={()=>this.onBlur()} placeholder="Shop opens" />

<Form.Control placeholder="Shop closes" type={this.state.focused === 'closes' ? 'time' : 'text'} onFocus={()=>this.onFocus('closes')} onBlur={()=>this.onBlur()} />
```